# R native time series: date data

Tags: r, plot, time-series

There are R native datasets, such as the `Nile` dataset, that are time series. However, if I actually look at the data set, be it as it was, after `as_tibble()`, after `as.data.frame()` – it doesn't matter –, there is only one column: `x` (which, in this specific case, is the "measurement of anual flow of the river"). However, if I `plot()` the data, in any of the three formats (raw, `tibble` or `data.frame`), I plots with the dates:

[image]

(Technically, the `x` axis label changes, but that's not the point).

Where are these dates stored? How can I access them (to use `ggplot()`, for example), or even – how can I *see* them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use str(Nile) or print(Nile), you'll see that the Nile data set is store in a Time-Series object. You can use the start(), end() and frequency() functions to extract those attribute then create a new column to store those informations.

```
data(Nile)    
new_df = data.frame(Nile)    
new_df$Time = seq(from = start(Nile)[[1]], to = end(Nile)[[1]], by = frequency(Nile))
```